# I have a problem when trying to access a button or an AppCompatEditText

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, null

I try to access the button or the AppCompatEditText using the findViewById() function

Kotlin code:

```
package com.example.qrecycle

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText

class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

//    val fullNameInput        : AppCompatEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextFullName)
//    val emailInput           : AppCompatEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail)
//    val passwordInput        : AppCompatEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword)
//    val confirmPasswordInput : AppCompatEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val registerBtn : Button = findViewById(R.id.registerBtn)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )

//        Toast.makeText(this, "I WORK!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        registerBtn.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "I work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_alternates"
        android:text="@string/registerMsg"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/backgroundColor"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp" >
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/fullNameText"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                android:textColorHint="@color/blackWithLowerOpacity"
                app:boxBackgroundMode="none">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextFullName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_edit_text_rounded"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,VisualLintTextFieldSize" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/emailText"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                android:textColorHint="@color/blackWithLowerOpacity"
                app:boxBackgroundMode="none" >

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_edit_text_rounded"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,VisualLintTextFieldSize" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/passwordText"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                android:textColorHint="@color/blackWithLowerOpacity"
                app:boxBackgroundMode="none" >

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_edit_text_rounded"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,VisualLintTextFieldSize" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:hint="@string/confirmPasswordText"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                android:textColorHint="@color/blackWithLowerOpacity"
                app:boxBackgroundMode="none" >

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextConfirmPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_edit_text_rounded"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,VisualLintTextFieldSize" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_button_dark_blue_rounded"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"
                android:letterSpacing=".05"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:text="@string/registerBtnText"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

When i try to run my application and get to that activity the app crashes and i get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.qrecycle, PID: 14505
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.qrecycle/com.example.qrecycle.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3682)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3942)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:109)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2345)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:191)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:804)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:922)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:889)

        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:691)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:264)
        at com.example.qrecycle.RegisterActivity.<init>(RegisterActivity.kt:13)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3669)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3942) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:109) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2345) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14505 SIG: 9
```

I also get tihs message:

```
V/AutofillManager: requestHideFillUi(null): anchor = null
V/AutofillManager: requestHideFillUi(null): anchor = null
V/TextView: notifyAutoFillManagerAfterTextChanged
V/AutofillManager: notifyValueChanged(1073741824): ignoring on state UNKNOWN
```

multiple times

I'm new to android development so any comment to make my code better is welcome.

I tried these :

- ```
  private lateinit val fullNameInput : AppCompatEditText

  val fullNameInputString = fullNameInput.text.toString()
  ```
- ```
  val fullNameInput : AppCompatEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextFullName)
  ```
- ```
  private val fullNameInput : AppCompatEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextFullName)
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access the UI elements that belong to "View" class before calling the "setContentView()" method. You can execute any code you want before the setContentView() method only it doesn't refer to (parts of) the View, which isn't set yet. So try using "findViewById()" method after calling "setContentView()".

Comment: I tried your solution and still, i have the exact same problem. Thank you

Comment: Make sure that the RegisterActivity is properly declared in the manifest file with the correct package name and activity name.

Comment: after debugging with commenting out variables i found out that this problem only occurs when the emailTextInput variable is uncommented and i still havent figure out why this happens